# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition owing to internal class not found. - Spring Boot + Spring Swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am developing **Spring Boot + Swagger** Implementation from link : **https://github.com/saurzcode/saurzcode-swagger-spring/**. In this project I simply updated the `'swagger-springmvc'` maven dependency to its latest version. When I did that I started facing the below error. Please guide how we can solve that.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition owing to internal class not found. This can happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:50)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:324)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:683)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:944)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:933)
    at com.saurzcode.swaggerdemo.Application.main(Application.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ApiInfo
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:458)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:663)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:385)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:354)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:150)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:93)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:44)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ApiInfo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- tag::actuator[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ajar</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-spring-mvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::actuator[] -->
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.saurzcode.swaggerdemo.Application</start-class>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>oss-jfrog-artifactory</id>
            <name>oss-jfrog-artifactory-releases</name>
            <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Application.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }
}
```

**HelloController.java**

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="saurzcode/hello")
    @ApiOperation(httpMethod = "GET", value = "Say Hello To World using Swagger")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Greetings from SaurzCode! ";
    }
}
```

**SwaggerConfig.java**

```
package com.saurzcode.swaggerdemo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig;
import com.mangofactory.swagger.plugin.EnableSwagger;
import com.mangofactory.swagger.plugin.SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin;
import com.wordnik.swagger.model.ApiInfo;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
public class SwaggerConfig {
    private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;

    @Autowired
    public void setSpringSwaggerConfig(SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig) {
        this.springSwaggerConfig = springSwaggerConfig;
    }

    @Bean //Don't forget the @Bean annotation
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation(){
        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .includePatterns("/saurzcode/.*");
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                "SaurzCode API",
                "API for Saurzcode",
                "Saurzcode API terms of service",
                "mail2saurzcode@gmail.com",
                "Saurzcode API Licence Type",
                "Saurzcode API License URL"
                );
        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but I'd upgrade to a newer version of Spring Boot if you can. 1.1.1 is a couple of years old now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only I see problem in an `import` statement of `ApiInfo`. In `Spring Swagger` version `1.0.2`, `ApiInfo` is a class from `com.mangofactory.swagger.models.dto` and not from `import` `com.wordnik.swagger.model.ApiInfo`; This will resolve your issue. Here is the output:

[image]